# How can I get an iframe to automatically resize whenever its "src" changes? (using jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I've written this code:

```
$('#main-content > iframe').load(function(){
    var $document = $(this.contentWindow.document);
    alert($document.height());
    $(this).height($document.height());
});
```

This works when the page first loads, but when the user changes the `src` of the iframe while using the page, it doesn't resize.

I change the src like this:

```
$('#main-content > iframe').attr("src",href);
```

No need to worry about XSS - it's all local.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#main-content > iframe').attr('src','onmouseclick.html');
    set();
});
function set() {
    $('#main-content > iframe').load(function(){
        var $document = $(this.contentWindow.document);
        //alert($document.height());
        $(this).height($document.height());
    });
}
</script>

<div id="main-content">
 <iframe id="main-contentiframe"></iframe>
 <a href="onmouseclick.html" onmouseover="$('#main-content > iframe').attr('src',this.href);set();return false;">Link</a>
 <a href="testscript.html" onmouseover="$('#main-content > iframe').attr('src',this.href);set();return false;">Link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't do it. It always alerts the initial height and never calculates a new one.

Comment: I edited it. Does that work? I've done this before, I'm just trying to remember how I did it. Basically, you need to make jQuery wait until the iFrame comepletely loads the new file before you attempt to discern the height.

Comment: I think that you actually want to trigger on the $(document).ready() function, I'm just trying to figure out a way to affect the iframe and not the current document in the iframe.

Comment: Yeah the `attr` function doesn't have a callback like that. Thanks for puutting thought into it - write back when you've got it?

Comment: I actually did get what I've edited in to work. Does that help?

Comment: EXCEPT, if the page has already loaded. Aaargh. The load() method only runs when the page hasn't been cached/loaded already.

Comment: Will have to test this in the morning. The iframe contents can't have changed height if the page has been cached no? So it doesn't matter?

Answer (score -1):

In Internet Explorer you can add an eventlistener to the `onreadystatechange` of iframes, in my experience it works more reliably than `load`

More information can be found at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536957%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

**Example:**

```
$('#main-content > iframe')[0].onreadystatechange = function(evt)
{
    if(window.event)
        evt = window.event;
    var $document = $(evt.srcElement);
    alert($document.height());
    $(this).height($document.height());
}
```

Beware, I have not tested the code